# Vertical Align in Livecode

Tags: vertical-alignment, livecode

I want to vertically align the text of the label in livecode like aligning to top, middle, or bottom.

```
   ----------------------------------
   |          top text               |
   |                                 |
   |                                 |
    ---------------------------------

    ---------------------------------
   |                                 |
   |          middle text            |
   |                                 |
    ---------------------------------

    ---------------------------------
   |                                 |
   |                                 |
   |          bottom text            |
    ---------------------------------
```

Is there any way to do that? If no, is there an alternate way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to automatically position label text as you describe.  However, unless you require the text formatting properties of a field, using a button as a label may better serve your needs because of its default ability to automatically center text vertically.

Something like the following should get you most of the way.  You can paste the script in the button directly and dispatch "updateMyTextAlignment <value>" to the button with a value of "top", "middle" or "bottom". But assuming you're going to have multiple custom labels in your stack, a better option would be to apply the following as a behavior to all your label buttons.

```
command updateMyTextAlignment pValue
   put effective textSize of me into TS
   put effective textHeight of me into TH
   switch pValue
      case "top"
         set topMargin of me to -(height of me) + TS + TH 
      break
      case "middle"
         set topMargin of me to 0 -- may need to adjust this amount
      break
      case "bottom"
         set topMargin of me to height of me - TS - TH
   end switch
end updateMyTextAlignment
```

Comment: I tried your code but I got an error, 
`Object: can't set this property` 
I put this script to the button `updateMyTextAlignment "top"` 
The error points at `set topMargin of me to - (height of me) + TS + TH` 
This is also happening when I choose middle and bottom.

Comment: Just tested in 6.7 and 7.0 and the code works fine using in both versions using updateMyTextAlignment "top" as you've written.  If you copy the script directly from here it should work, as opposed to retyping it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no option in the properties window but you can do this with a simple script like

```
 set the topMargin of field theField to (round(((the height of field theField - the formattedHeight of field theField)/2)) + the topMargin of field theField)
```

Example for top margin

Update:
Easiest example for top margin:

```
set the topMargin of field theField to 0
```

and then adjust 0 to whatever value you want from the top, e.g. your font size or so.

for middle I'd use something like

```
set the topMargin of field theField to (the height of field theField / 2)
```

and maybe adjust this by factoring the font size in too.

Comment: I tried your code. The text is displayed at the buttom, how can I make it centered/top aligned?

Comment: It worked but the text is not actually centered. I edited your suggestions and tried this `set the topMargin of field theField to (the height of field theField / 2) - (the textsize of field theField / 2)`. In top alignment, it only shows half of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, and this is only a partial answer but some might find this useful:

For vertically centering 1 line of text in a field, I use this code, courtesy of @BerndN:

```
local tFieldY, tFormatRect, tFormatheight, tFormatHalfHeight, tCurrFormatTop, tCenterField_To_TopTextDiff
put item 2 of the loc of field 1 into tfieldY
   
put the formattedRect of line 1 to - 1 of field 1 into tFormatRect
put item 4 of tFormatRect - item 2 of tFormatRect into tFormatHeight
put tFormatHeight div 2 into tFormatHalfHeight

put item 2 of tFormatRect into tCurrFormatTop
put tfieldY - tCurrFormatTop into tCenterField_To_TopTextDiff

set the topMargin of field 1 to the topMargin of field 1 \
      + tCenterField_To_TopTextDiff - tFormatHalfHeight
```

This works well for text that is 1 line - not tested on multiline. Great for when resizing field and wanting to keep the line of text aligned in the middle vertically.